# create a folder which links multiple folders

Tags: windows, links, directory-junction

Suppose there are directories as below:

```
D:\SVN1\a\xml
D:\SVN1\b\xml
D:\SVN1\c\xml
D:\SVN1\d\xml
```

and

```
D:\SVN2\xml
```

I would like to merge all xml folders/files under a b c d of SVN1 and link the same to xml in SVN2.

Is it possible to do this? I have used junctions only with one to one mapping of folders. I am not sure how to merge multiple folders into one link. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not really have a feature such as linking folders. But there is a way you could achieve this on Vista and up.

You can create a new "library" (windows already provides libraries for Pictures, Documents, Downloads, Music, ...) and include all those xml folders in the library.

[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-new-library) is a tutorial on how to create this library including a link on how to add folders to this library.

This library will be shown in "My Computer" in the Windows Explorer and is no folder on its own.

---

If you need it to be a folder, I'm afraid that there's now other way than [creating a folder with multiple shortcuts in it](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-delete-shortcut#1TC=windows-7).

Comment: the folders in real scenario contains hundreds of files, and the content keeps varying, few may be added or few may be deleted. a folder junction would take care of all that, but creating and deleting the shortcuts wouldnt serve the purpose i guess. thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

There are also two efforts (not much alive), of which I know for implementing unionfs for windows:

- https://code.google.com/p/winunionfs/
- https://github.com/alur/WinUnionFS